# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my Code

*`App.tsx`*

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { TextField } from './components/TextField';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField name='fef' age=12/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*`TextField.tsx`*

```js
import React,{useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

interface Props{
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export const TextField:React.FC<Props> = ({name,age}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Hello {name}, and I know that you are {age} years old</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I am getting this ***Error!***

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
TextField.tsx(5, 5): The expected type comes from property 'age' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

[image]

What should I have to do?

*Please give me a **Solution** for this. I am New to React and Typescript.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `age` prop such as `age={12}`. Here's the full code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export const TextField: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, age }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Hello {name}, and I know that you are {age} years old
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField name="fef" age={12} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cocky-sea-edyrw]

Answer (score 4):

Numbers as props should be passed inside curly brackets. Only strings can be passed without the curly brackets, but they have to be wrapped inside the quotes, just like your `name` prop.

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField name='fef' age={12}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code instead:

```
age={12}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by changing the TextField.tsx return to code below,

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField name='fef' age={12}/>
    </div>
  );
```

this

```
age=12
```

give you "12"
but

```
age={12}
```

gives you a number